# Capturing the console output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, console

I am running a Hadoop hive query from shell script. This is how I am doing it in my shell script.

```
echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test" | hive
```

I want to capture the output whatever `hive` command outputs. So, I am running my shell script as:

```
./hivequery.sh 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

But, I am not able to capture the output of the `hive` command. How can I do that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `tee`? Does it work with simple redirection, `./hivequery.sh 2>&1 > output.txt`? Does it work if you run the echo and hive commands directly from the terminal?

Comment: Use `|&` instead of the old `2>&1 |` syntax, it's shorter. Try without `tee` first, then read `man tee` and play around with the parameters to get it to do what you want. If tee doesn't work, you'll need to find an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. I checked with the redirection, but it didn't work. :-(

Comment: Did you try `script`?  E.g.  `script elm` will capture all output from the program elm, including colour codes and refreshes`. The copy of all output will be logged in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I added the redirection operator in the shell command itself inside the script.

```
echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test" | hive 2>&1
```

The `script` too worked.

```
script -c ./myscript.sh output.txt
```

Comment: Go with `script` as @Hennes suggested above. A much more cleaner idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -S -e 'select a.col from tab1 a' > a.txt
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli